# mysql query issue to select total records per day in two tables

Tags: mysql, sum, union

i want to get SUM/Total records each day in a month from two tables,when i run my query on single table,it works but then commulative is not working...like this is for first table which is ok.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, count(id) as tot_rent
from crm_rentals WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
group by date(dateadded)
```

this is for second table which is also ok.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, count(id) as tot_rent
from crm_sales WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
group by date(dateadded)
```

Issue is when i want to find sum of each day of the result,it is not working properly..here is my final query

```
select dateadded,count(tot_rent) as tot_rent
from ( select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, count(id) as tot_rent
from crm_rentals WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
group by date(dateadded)
union
select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, count(id) as tot_rent
from crm_sales WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
group by date(dateadded)) s group by date(dateadded)
```

table structure for crm_rentals(first table,date=Y-m-d)

```
id -----dateadded
15------2013-04-02
16------2013-04-03
17------2013-04-03
```

table 2 crm_sales

```
id------dateadded
 7------2013-04-02
```

Result should be

```
dateadded-----tot_rent
04/02/2013 ----2
04/03/2013  ---2 //this line is not shown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first query gives

```
id -----dateadded
1------2013-04-02
2------2013-04-03
```

second query gives

```
id -----dateadded
1------2013-04-02
```

so union will give

```
1------2013-04-02
2------2013-04-03
1------2013-04-02
```

its group will do

```
2------2013-04-02
1------2013-04-03
```

correct approach would be

```
15------2013-04-02
16------2013-04-03
17------2013-04-03
```

UNION

```
 7------2013-04-02
```

Then Group will give

```
2------2013-04-02
2------2013-04-03
```

try this:

```
select dateadded,count(tot_rent) as tot_rent
from ( select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, id as tot_rent
from crm_rentals WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
union
select DATE_FORMAT(date(dateadded),'%m/%d/%Y') as dateadded, id as tot_rent
from crm_sales WHERE YEAR(dateadded) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(dateadded) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
) s group by dateadded
```

Comment: i am not using +,i want count..mean HOW MANY RECORDS ADDED IN BOTH TABLES ON A DAY

Comment: can you give an example of data in two tables and your expected result

Comment: please check now, i added example data

Comment: I tested the query by creating same data and same table. I am getting 2 for 2012-04-02 and 2 for 2013-04-03. Though there was some error in the query i.e. "group by date(dateadded)" is incorrect as dateadded is already a string so i am editing the answer to correct this.